# Winjs background process conflict

Tags: winjs

my windows 8 app works in the following way:-I have a background process which sends the data which is stored in indexdb to the database.This background process runs every 5 mins automatically.When I am editing or changing any value saved in my list this background method is conflicting with the same value which I am editing and this shows the list in an incorrect manner.I want a solution where I can stop the data which I am editing from conflicting with the background process.